# To delete git remote branch

Tags: git, github

How delete git remote branch when :

```
git push -d master
fatal: --delete doesn't make sense without any refs
```

cannot work ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I delete a Git branch locally and remotely?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2003505/how-do-i-delete-a-git-branch-locally-and-remotely)

Answer (score 1):

very easy :

```
git push origin --delete <branch name>
```